# Run Web Application in Virtual Directory

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to run my web application for test purposes in a virtual directory.

I have done this steps from this [MS Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6cw6cfs%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

- In Visual Studio, open an existing Web application project, or create a new one.
- In the Project menu, click Properties, and then click Web.
- Click Use Local IIS Web server.
- Enter a URL for the project, and then click Create Virtual Directory.

But after this configuration I get a ***HTTP-Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error***

Details: There are duplicate entries in the web.config File

But the web.config file hasn't changed. Without the Virtual Directory the site is starting up as expected.

any ideas?

Comment: which application pool mode you are using? classic or integrated?

Comment: Please make sure that your application pool for virtual directory is pointing to correct .net version.